# Constructor injection is not working in kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have converted my dagger module, component and classes into kotlin. Facing below error when using the constructor injection in Model class:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: dataManager.appSettings must not be null
```

Here is my Module class:

```
@Module
class BaseModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideBaseViewModel(application: Application, dataManager: DataManager, serviceConnector: ServiceConnector, compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable): BaseModel {
        return BaseModel(application, dataManager, serviceConnector, compositeDisposable)
    }
}
```

Here is my Model Class which has constructor injection:

```
class BaseModel @Inject constructor(application: Application, dataManager: DataManager,compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable) : BaseViewModel(application, dataManager, compositeDisposable) {

    val appSettings: AppSettings
        get() = dataManager.appSettings
}
```

Here is the component class:

```
@Component(modules = [BaseModule::class])
interface BaseComponent {
    fun inject(activity: BaseActivity)
}
```

Comment: `appSettings` appears to be `null`, not `dataManager`

Comment: you may try having `Application?`, `DataManeger?` and so on for types in the constructor to allow `null` values for these parameters. It is likely, you do not have `appSettings`

Comment: Fixed by changing AppSettings to AppSettings?

Comment: that's not really a fix

Answer (score 0):

Is `dataManager.appSettings` of a nullable type?

If yes, you might make the `AppSettings` nullable, like this:

```
val appSettings: AppSettings?
```

Comment: How does the first proposal solve the issue of *not crashing*?